# How to access chrome developer tools for an android device connected to a remote machine?

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging, mobile-webkit

I have an android device connected to a server in my lab and want to access chrome developer tools for the device from my laptop. How can I do it ?
I went through https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging but this seems to work only if the device is directly connected to laptop.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: If its not possible at the moment, all ideas welcome on how to approach towards achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, technically the device has to be connected to adb. You can use an app like [ADB Konnect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rockolabs.adbkonnect), or [open a port via the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp) and connect to it through the network.